# Binding global scope variable to directive local variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm having trouble understanding scope linking between controllers and directives.

What I'm trying to do (which should help me learn a lot) is bind `$scope.systems` in my controller to `data` in my directive.

So I setup a simple directive call:

```
<combobox data="systems"></combobox>
```

I also tried binding the variable, but it didn't make sense to me.

```
<combobox data="{{systems}}"></combobox>
```

Then I created my driver as such

```
.directive('combobox', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/angular/directives/combobox.php',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs.data);
            $timeout(function () {
                console.log(scope.systems);
                console.log($scope[attrs.data]);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

I considered adding a scope parameter to the directive return

```
scope: {
    'systems': '='
}
```

Or

```
scope: {
    'systems': '=data'
}
```

I've been able to setup simple directives where values are bound to the directive scope, and they've worked. Now I'm trying to create a reusable directive where I can tell it what data from the controller scope to use, and I'm just stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Although I'm not sure why your template is a php file...

```
<combobox data="foo"></combobox>
<combobox data="bar"></combobox>

app.directive('combobox', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            //this will set $scope.systems
            //with the value gotten from evaluating what is in
            //the data attribute
            'systems': '=data'
        },
        templateUrl: '/angular/directives/combobox.php',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.systems);
        }
    }
});
```

BTW, don't use `replace`. The Angular team said it will probably disappear soon because it is causing too many issues and is not that necessary anyway.

Comment: I'm learning Angular by replacing parts of a current website with Angular; parts of it are still PHP driven, so out of habit, I create PHP files. I know I can just make them HTML. Also, isn't replace necessary for when you want to pass an ID or class? Finally, that doesn't quite do what I want. I want to be able to reference regardless of what I pass to data. In this case, its `systems`, in another it may be `users`. Referencing `scope.systems` removes the point of an attribute.

Comment: ``replace`` will just replace the tag from your markup with the primary tag from your directive's template, trying to merge the attributes (and sometimes failing to do so correctly). If you want to add a class to the directive's element (ie the one from your main markup), just do so using the ``element`` parameter of your directive's ``link`` function.

Comment: I don't think you're getting how the ``=`` works. I just edited my answer to make it clearer. It should work the way you want.

Comment: Yah, I think I'm missing some fundamental part of how the isolate scopes work. Your code works (I tried something almost identical before, not sure why it failed), so now I have to go back to the basics and understand WHY it works.

Comment: There are a few concepts that are not easy to grasp in Angular. It took me a while. You'll need to understand scopes (and scope inheritance), data-binding, watchers, expressions (see $parse and $scope.$eval)... start by reading the angular doc. And I think there are some interesting posts on SO.